# Create form for daily attendance report from access

Tags: custom-form

Sadly, I'm limited on both experience and resources. I have OOTB SharePoint, Infopath Designer, and Access 2013 at my disposable.

I've created a table with Employee ID, Job Title, Name, Department, and Workcenter.

I would like to create some type of form that can be submitted to a form library in SharePoint for managers to mark their workcenter employees present for the day. Ideally, this would look like a drop down to select the workcenter then names would appear with a simple checkbox for present or not present.

I've been successful creating a data connection to SP from access and then attempting to turn that data connection into a repeating table in Infopath but I can't filter the data. Every entry on the table appears even when I run filtering formulas.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Please attach the screen shot of the infopath form.